# Alerting Users of CiviCRM Maintenance

Tags: dashboard, user

I thought I had seen, and used, this feature in the past, but perhaps it was a different CRM product I was testing.  How do I put a scrolling alert up to inform users of system maintenance, or new feature improvements, or a friendly "replace the used toilet paper rolls" message?  (Ok, if you do the last one, you may need to seek help, but you get the idea.) I can't seem to find it via menu diving or Google-Fu.

(I'm using Wordpress, but I would think it would be a core feature.)

Comment: No recollection of this feature.

Comment: Drat.  Guess I'll see if there is a WP plugin for such functionality then.  BTW, I get the feeling that the API framework already would support such a feature, but the feature hasn't been built yet.  Then again, I could have been reading too much into the API documentation that I quickly perused looking for this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of such a feature.

A (somewhat drastic) workaround would be to remove "access CiviCRM" permission from your users during maintenance.

You could probably customize the "access denied" message that WP gives, to be a bit more friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question asked is generic - I'll add that in Drupal - you would invoke the maintenance mode screen - on that you can display a customized message.